# Default initialization of member variables or add more constructors? Best practice for creating classes?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default-value

Following a tutorial on [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-programming/non-static-member-initialization/comment-page-2/#comment-534498) which discusses declaring member variables outside of constructors. However in previous lessons the author mentions that minimizing the amount of constructors is optimal and can be done by using default values in the parameters of a constructor. This is confusing to me because suddenly there are two places to give default values, directly where you define your member variable, and in the parameter of the constructor. Additionally, it seemed like the whole point of defining default values outside of the constructor was to prevent redundant code because "if you update the default value for a member, you need to touch each constructor".

Here's the example used:

```cpp
class Ball
{
  private:
    std::string m_color{ "black" }; //default value "black" declared here
    double m_radius{};
 
  public:
    Ball(double radius)
        : m_radius{ radius } {}
 
    Ball(const std::string& color = "black", double radius = 10.0) //and here!
        : m_color{ color },
          m_radius{ radius } {}
 
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "color: " << m_color << ", radius: " << m_radius << '\n';
    }
};
```

It seems like the solution given by the tutorial uses "black" in two places, contradicting the idea of having all default values in one place to minimize changing constructors. I'm wondering what the best practice here is, and if there is a better way to write this class.

Comment: It'd be easier to do this if you reversed the order in the second constructor, as then it'd work like the first.

Comment: @tadman Wouldn't I then lose the possibility to construct a Ball with just the color as a parameter? Something like Ball b{"red"}; wouldn't be possible anymore? I might be misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: Since you need to specify arguments in the order they are given, and you can't skip any per-se, then you need to carefully consider which order makes the most sense from a user perspective. Sometimes it's unavoidable that you'll need multiple constructors.

Comment: If, one day, C++ allows named arguments like Python this will be moot. You can just do `Ball(radius=3.9)`.

Comment: The above code allow code like this `Ball b;  std::string s;  b = s;`  I would be conceded about the tutorials quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your constructors to not have any default parameters by adding some constructors

```
std::string m_color{ "black" };
double m_radius{10.};  // specify default value here, exactly like color
 
public:

Ball() = default;  // add a default constructor
    
Ball(double radius)   // keep the constructor taking a double
    : m_radius{ radius } {}
 
Ball(const std::string& color)  // add a constructor taking only a string
    : m_color{ color } {}

Ball(const std::string& color, double radius)  // don't provide defaults for the
        : m_color{ color },                    // 2 argument constructor
          m_radius{ radius } {}
```

These overloads for the constructor are equivalent to your version, and the defaults are specified only once.

Comment: Is the only disadvantage with this method being the fact that you have to explicitly write more constructors for your class?

Comment: Yes, I can't think of any other issues with this approach, at least for a class with 2 members where either member can use the default value while the other is provided by the user.